# В какие директории проекта складывать какие файлы

Tags: python, проектирование, файлы, проект

И снова здравствуйте.

Я никогда не писал крупные проекты, и сейчас передо мной стал вопрос, как должна выглядеть структура файлов и директорий в проекте, что куда складывать и во что вкладывать. Гугление далось мне очень сложно, поэтому я прошелся по репозиториям крупных проектов на гитхабе и получил некоторое пересечение папок:

- src - как я понимаю, основной исходный код продукта - то что мы устанавливаем, подключаем и т.д.;
- test - юнит-тесты и, наверное, все остальные;
- docs - документация по проекту и его исходному коду;
- examples - это примеры, в этом я уверен; :)
- bin - папка, которая есть везде, но содержимое ее непонятно.

Собственно, имея этот список, я хочу спросить у вас, все ли я правильно понял и какие еще есть нормы и правила по этому поводу.

Также интересует конкретный случай: у меня в проекте есть файлы, которые не используются напрямую в коде проекта, но нужны в процессе разработки (например, я общаюсь со сторонними сайтами и в одном файле экспериментирую с тем, как правильно проанализировать стороннюю информацию, вывожу метаданные об этой информации и т.д., этот файл не имеет отношения к основному коду, но очень упрощает разработку, и я хотел бы иметь его в репозитории) - в какую директорию складывать их?

**UPDATE** - пишу на python, не привязываясь к фреймворкам по типу django.

Comment: Проект на Java?

Comment: @Xyanight, нет, на python. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @zesudageg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Пост старый, но решил отметиться:

1. структура максимально приближена к структуре каталогов в Linux. Основная причина: создание dep/rpm/... пакетов, которые должны при установке соответствовать требованиям ОС.
2. структура каталогов копирует структуру Linux, но поскольку приложение запускается в изолированном окружении (virtualenv, Docker), то размещается это все в своем изолированном окружении.

Отсюда имеется:

- bin - сполняемые скрипты;
- lib - библиотеки;
- etc - конфиги, настройки;
- var - переменные данные;

  - var/log - логи работы;
- share - какие-то общие данные, ни разу не использовал, обычно не создаю.

В идеале же стараюсь даже изолированный проект делать так, чтобы его из него можно было сделать системный пакет или хотя бы тар для установки pip'ом

Comment: а можно пример такого проекта?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Это каждый решает сам. Я пишу на Python также и уже определился с СВОЕЙ собственной структурой каталогов в проектах. Написал небольшую тузлу для автоматической генерации каталогов при создании нового проекта.

Итак, в корневой директории проекта находятся папки и файлы:

**[data]** - папка содердит обязательные подкаталоги image, language, также в ней я храню все остальное, типа файлов, которые вы не знаете, куда деть;
__________**[image]** - графика проекта;
__________**[language]** - файлы языковых локализаций;
_______________*language_rus.txt*
**[libs]** - модули и дополнительные библиотеки проекта;
**[LISENSE]** - текстовые файлы лицензии;
**[Plugins]** - каталог для плагинов проекта;
*setting.ini* - файл настроей проекта;
*nameProject.py* - это код запускающий loadplugin.py и program.py, в случае ошибки,          пишет лог и выводит окно с ее текстом, своего рода - стартер;
*loadplugin.py* - загружает плагины перед выполнением программного кода в program.py;
*program.py* - собственно, сам програмный код проекта;

В итоге получается вот что:

[image]

Чисто и понятно!

Как видите, все просто. Рано или поздно, вы должны были прити к вопросу о структурировании каталогов своего проекта!

Comment: Получается, никаких норм нет и каждый организовывает структуру проекта как хочет (ну или максимально логично по его мнению)?

Comment: Да. По крайней мере в Python. Я, например, придерживаюсь своей структуры каталогов, уже пару лет. Такая структура проекта расширяемя, достаточно добовить необходимый функционал в папку Plugins, проста и застрахована от ошибок.